# Comment system won't work through php

Tags: php, html, css

A comment posting tutorial for a guestbook type situation I watched on the internet works fine for many others but for me I keep having

```
" . $name. ":
" . $content . "
"); fclose ($handle); } ?>
```

appear above the comment box. Also it does not post anything after doing all that in php. Here is the code:

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST ['name'];
    $content = $_POST ['commentcontent'];
    $handle = fopen("JackPackNetwork.html","a");
    fwrite ($handle, "<b>" . $name. "</b>:<br/>" . $content  .  "<br/>");
    fclose ($handle);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method= "POST">

Comments: <textarea rows= "10" cols= "30" name= "commentContent"></textarea> <br/>
Name: <input type= "text" name = "name"> <br/>
<input type= "submit" value = "Post!"> <br/>
</form>
<?php include "JackPackNetwork.html"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Specifically I want to link to JackPackNetwork.html and update the comments with the ability of someone being able to put their name on it as well. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Names of variables are case sensitive. You must change `$_POST ['commentcontent']` to `$_POST ['commentContent']` (as it is written in your textarea `name` attribute). Except this trouble your code is correctly work for me

Comment: Looks like your PHP isn't being compiled, and being interpreted add HTML instead. There are many reasons this could happen - is it a .php file? Is Apache/PHP running?

Comment: I put the file as localhost through wampserver as I spent some time trying to get apache to run but couldn't figure it out so I went with Wampserver.

Comment: Then I went to check it and it posts this at the top of the page                                                                                                                   :if($_POST){ $name = $_POST ['name']; $content = $_POST ['commentContent']; $handle = fopen("JackPackNetwork.html","a"); fwrite ($handle, "" . $name. ":
" . $content . "
"); fclose ($handle); } ?>  Also the comment system is not posting. Thanks for the help so far guys.

Comment: Wamp server was easier to install than apache but could the issue be that I'm using Wampserver?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php

if($_POST){
$name = $_POST ['name'];
$content = $_POST ['commentContent'];
$handle = fopen("JackPackNetwork.html","a");
fwrite ($handle, "<b>" . $name. "</b>:<br/>" . $content  .  "<br/>");
fclose ($handle);



}

?>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method= "POST">

Comments: <textarea rows= "10" cols= "30" name= "commentContent"></textarea>      <br/>
Name: <input type= "text" name = "name"> <br/>
<input type= "submit" value = "Post!"> <br/>
</form>
<?php require_once("JackPackNetwork.html"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**MISTAKE**

1. array index are case sensitive so $content post request fetch should be done correctly.

**Suggestion**

1. Use require_once() instead of include().

Comment: Why should he **always** use require_once() instead of include() ?

Comment: include() will throw warning and rest of the script will execute, whereas require() halts the program there itself.require_once() will insure that a particular file is not included twice.

Comment: But if it fails, does he want everything to stop/break, or does he want it to continue without? What i'm trying to say is that it is a personal preference. And they should **not** always use the same if they don't want.

Comment: It was my mistake to add that in mistake i have corrected that and its a suggestion. Yes you are right that it is personal preference.

Comment: I used wampserver and this comes up at the top of the page:

Comment: if($_POST){ $name = $_POST ['name']; $content = $_POST ['commentContent']; $handle = fopen("JackPackNetwork.html","a"); fwrite ($handle, "" . $name. ":
" . $content . "
"); fclose ($handle); } ?>

Comment: still having trouble processing the form as well

Comment: Hey I checked my php on a website online and I got the following error: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in your code on line 14

    ?><?php require_once() "JackPackNetwork.html"; ?>

PHP Syntax Check: Errors parsing your code

Comment: @cobra101 you have used `require_once()"JackPackNetwork.html";` instead you should use `require_once("JackPackNetwork.html")`

Comment: Hi I'm still having the same issue with the text I mentioned above appearing when I test it on Wampserver.

Comment: I have fixed the code you mentioned but I am still having this issue